# not showing message diologe with JOptione pane

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextfield, joptionpane

i have written a code to create a sms form and i want to add the ability to show error message when the text area is empty. i put JOptionpane in my code but diologe dose not appear when i run the program! here is my code

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("?????? ? ????? ?????");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();


    JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();

    txtPath = new JTextField();
    txtPath.setBounds(150, 10, 200, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPath);
    txtPath.setColumns(10);

    txtPath2 = new JTextField();
    txtPath2.setBounds(150, 65, 200, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPath2);
    txtPath2.setColumns(20);

    JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("?????");
    btnBrowse.setBounds(5, 10, 87, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

    final JButton ok = new JButton("?????");
    ok.setBounds(250, 230, 87, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(ok);

    JButton cancel = new JButton("???");
    cancel.setBounds(110, 230, 87, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cancel);


    final JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
    textarea.setBounds(50, 100, 300, 100);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);
    textarea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);




    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    progressBar.setSize(10, 1);
    progressBar.setForeground(Color.blue);
    frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);





    btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

            // For Directory
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

            // For File
            //fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

            fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            int rVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                txtPath.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", "txt", "rtf"));

            }
        }
    });



   ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(textarea.getLineCount()>=1)
            {


          test t=new test();
            ReadTextFile readTextFile=new ReadTextFile();
            t.testMethode(txtPath2.getText(), textarea.getText(),readTextFile.readFile(txtPath.getText()) );
        }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    });




        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


    }
    }
```

Comment: What would make your `textarea` have a line count of 0? And when would that happen?

Comment: when the user enter no character in the field i want to show the alarm window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI's are event driven environments.  Something happens, you respond to it.

You `if-else` statement will never be `false` because the time it is executed, the `textarea` will be blank (have no text).

You need to respond to some event (ie `send` for example) at which time you would make your check to valid the form.

Take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private final JTextArea msg;

        public TestPane() {

            msg = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            JButton send = new JButton("Send");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(new JScrollPane(msg), gbc);
            add(send, gbc);

            send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (msg.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                        // Send msg
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Please write something (nice)", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**Updated based on changes to the answer by the OP**

`if(textarea.getLineCount()>=1)` will always return `true`.  Try using `msg.getText().trim().length() > 0` instead to determine the `JTextArea` contains text or not...

**Updated**

mKobel has made an excellent point.  You really should avoid using `null` layouts.  You don't control what font size or screen DPI/resolution your application might need to work on.  Layout managers take out the guess work.

You should try checking out [A visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more details

Comment: So example the logic.  If the text area contains no text you want to display an error message?  Or if the text area contains text, you want to display an error message?

Comment: @mKorbel Oh, I have a fan club, they just like throwing darts at me ;)

Comment: @mKorbel I don't mind down votes so long as some one can explain why